# Methods inside a scala object singleton are not static?

Tags: java, scala, singleton

Here is a skeleton singleton

```
object MrJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  }
}
```

After compiling (scalac) javap  shows me:

```
$javap -classpath target/classes com.blazedb.scalademo.MrJob$
Compiled from "SDemo.scala"
public final class com.blazedb.scalademo.MrJob$ extends java.lang.Object{
    public static final com.blazedb.scalademo.MrJob$ MODULE$;
    public static {};
    public void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

So then how to make the main method static?  thanks

Update (with answer from Robin Green below): i want to add the answer from below in this text for easier viewing:

```
 $javap -classpath target/classes com.blazedb.scalademo.MrJob
Compiled from "SDemo.scala"
public final class com.blazedb.scalademo.MrJob extends java.lang.Object{
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Comment: The values created by Scala's `object` keyword are *only* singletons when defined at global scope (or within other objects or obects that are within other object, and so on). An object inside a trait or class is by no means a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `MrJob` (no `$`) you should find there is a static bridge method, if I remember correctly.

Comment: yes ur correct, it is in the MrJob.  That is some magic under the scala covers.

Comment: Since MrJob is what Java code will see (unless it's doing something fancy like reflection) this shouldn't be a problem for interop then, right?

Comment: No it is fine. I was trying to use MrJob$ from java.